# confusing result from pd .cut interval

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

I need to create range for the interval by using the pd.cut. My minimum    value is `0`  and the maximum is `4412429728.0.` but the problem is the minimum value in the first  interval start with `(-4412429.728, 44124297.28]` but it is should start with this interval `(0, 44124297.28]` is that way that i can cut the interval in a range not equal ?

```py
df_inputs_prepr['Pre_STANDARD_SALES_bins'] = pd.cut(df_inputs_prepr['Pre_STANDARD_SALES'], 50)
```

I expected the value start with with the minmum value 0 
and the range of the interval is not equal

Comment: another idea: you can actually create your own `buckets` or `range` and map your grouping there.

Answer (score 1):

The best option might be to define your own bins and to specify that anything below 0 should get one single label. For example:

```
pd.cut(df_inputs_prepr['Pre_STANDARD_SALES'], bins=[np.NINF, 0, 5, 10, 15, np.PINF], labels=['<=0', '0-5', '5-10', '10-15', '>15'])
```

You might also want to use `np.arange` with a particular `step` size (e.g. 50) to automatically generate the buckets for values greater than zero at particular intervals.

Comment: Hi Vald i want my bin start with min value of Pre_STANDARD_SALES

Comment: The above uses negative infinity as the lower limit of the first bucket which will in practice be your minimum value.